# Обновление картинки jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Делаю плагин на WP + jQuery.
Нужно: обновление картинки после изменений.
Форма ввода текста на картинку + указание размера шрифта.
Отправляю на сервер, картинке генерируется, выводится. Все хорошо.
Изменяю размер текста на картинке, отправляю снова, генерируется, все хорошо НО!
На сервере картинка изменена и сохранена.
у клиента никаких изменений, нужно заменить src картинки у клиента средствами jQuery.
и тут начались качели.
Я пробовал:

```js
jQuery(".imgfont").attr("src", imgurl);
```

```js
jQuery(".imgfont")removeAttr("src").attr("src", imgurl);
```

Так же добавлял Math.random() и  new Date().getTime() как дополнительный параметр "?random="
Пробовал делать через setInterval()

Меняется текст на картинке, размеры картинке не меняются, меняется ее 'вес.'
Имя картинки задается при начальной ее генерации, и оно не меняется и не должно меняться.

Answer (score 0):

Обновляем атрибут `src` добавляя к нему текущее время пользователя в миллисекундах

**jQuery**

```
$('.imgfont').attr('src', function(i,attr){
  return attr+'?'+(new Date().getTime());
});
```

Comment: После добавления пишет в консоль  Uncaught ReferenceError: JQuery is not defined